# Is there any way to display the link of a Wordpress page without relying in its slug (or full path)?

Tags: links

Say I want to add this link: http://localhost/taiwantalk2/user-login/
Which is a Page with a template called **page user-login.php**:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: bbPress - User Login
 *
 * @package bbPress
 * @subpackage Theme
 */

// No logged in users
bbp_logged_in_redirect();

// Begin Template
get_header(); ?>
```

I used to just paste the url of the site (using template_directory) plus the slug (/user-login).
The problem is that I have to stick with he same slug (/user-login).

Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want a URL to your page, that will work even if you change the page slug?

You can do this by linking to the **default permalink** for that particular page, for example http://localhost/taiwantalk2/?page_id=139.

This URL will always work even if your permalinks are updated. WordPress handles the redirects for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to create a link to a page that is using your login template?

If that is what you want, you might query the database like that:

```sql
SELECT p.ID FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN postmeta pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
WHERE
    p.post_status = 'publish'
    AND
    pm.meta_key = '_wp_page_template'
    AND
    pm.meta_value = 'user-login.php'
LIMIT 1;
```

using `$wpdb`. This of course relies on the fact that there's only one page using that template. You can then use the resulting id with `get_permalink()`.